# Cygwin shortcut to start xterm

Tags: cygwin, xterm, xlaunch

I've been using cygwin for very long time. Back in the day, we used to be able to create a shortcut and it automatically starts X and starts an Xterm with the preferences saved in a file.

Today, I'm finding myself launching xlaunch, and then clicking throw a few dialogs to start xterm. Is there a way I can shortcut all this and just click one shortcut to get the result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `startxwin` that belongs to `xinit` package 
Create you customized script from the baseline:

```
cp /etc/defaults/etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc ~/.startxwinrc
```

remove a bit of the duplication at the begin of `~/.startxwinrc`
to avoid a recursive call and at the end add how many xterm calls
you want before the Menu manager.

```
/usr/bin/xterm  &
exec /usr/bin/xwin-xdg-menu
```

Comment: I can't find any startxwinrc in /etc/X11/xinit/

Comment: Sorry typo  it is `/etc/defaults/etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc`

Comment: unfortunately there isn't a directory in /etc/defaults/etc/X11/... so the directory /etc/defaults/etc/X11/xinit/ doesn't exist

Comment: Have you installed `xinit` package ?