# Create Windows 10 shortcut for Cygwin xterm command

Tags: cygwin, x11

In recent years, Cygwins X-windows icon in the notification area doesn't provide an option to start an xterm.  If I mistakenly exit my last xterm, I need a way to launch a new one.  Currently, I exit X-Windows, remove `~/.server*` files, and `/tmp/.X*`, then restart X-Windows.

I found a command that I can enter after clicking on the Windows Start button:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -display :0
```

However, it also starts a DOS window in addition to the xterm.  If I close the DOS window, the xterm disappears.

I tried the following, with the same effect:

```
cmd /q /c "C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -display :0"

cmd /q /c "start /b /min C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -display :0"

start /b cmd /q /c "C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -display :0"

start /b C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -display :0
```

Note that the two commands that *lead* with `start` aren't recognized when I type the command after clicking on the Windows Start button, so I can only use them by manually opening a `cmd` window.  But the problem remains the same; I have a lingering command window.

In separate trials, I also tried putting each of the above three commands into `~/bin/myXterm.bat`, clicking the Windows Start button, and typing the full Windows path to `myXterm.bat`.  Same result -- a lingering command window in addition to the desired xterm

**Is there a command that *won't* leave a command window lingering?**

I plan to type the command after clicking on the Windows Start button, then right-click the resulting icon in the Taskbar and create an icon from it.  I can then find a way to pin it to the start menu or as a persistent shortcut in the Taskbar.  It would be preferable if the host shell for xterm did not even appear on the taskbar, as the taskbar is often crowded and extra icons simply create cognitive noise (but small ones for shortcuts are OK).

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876197/cygwin-shortcut-to-start-xterm) and
[this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280315/opening-cygwin-x11-applications-in-windows-10-from-desktop-shortcuts) are not the same as mine.

Comment: The default window manager for cygwin is XFCE, you don't use it ?

Comment: I haven't heard of it, but I have limited knowledge of X under the hood.
The following are available under Cywin-X in the Start menu:
User script= `C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; XSESSION_ICON= exec /usr/bin/startx /etc/X11/xinit/Xsession xinit-compat"`;
XLaunch= `C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/xlaunch.exe`;
XWin Server= `C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; exec /usr/bin/startxwin"`. Hmmm, I suppose I could have saved the afternoon by using Cygwin's `run,exe`.

Comment: Having googled XFCE, it's not what I'm looking for. If I wanted to use a strictly Unix environment, I would use TWM. But I don't, and I have the root window hidden.  I rely on Windows 10 behaviour to move, size, and dock windows. All the X clients look like Windows 10 windows. Cognitively, to me, that's full integration with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

**What worked**

I right-clicked my desktop and chose to create a new shortcut.  I specified the following for the `Target` field

```
 powershell "start C:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe -Args \" -display :0 \" -WindowStyle Hidden"
```

For the `Start in` field, I specified `C:\cygwin64\home\%USERNAME%` (use the Cygwin user home directory as it is set up in your installation).

I then right-clicked the shortcut and chose to pin it to the Start Menu.

**What doesn't work**

I initially put the above command into `~/bin/MyXterm.bat`.  I can create a shortcut, but I cannot pin it to the Start menu.  I don't have that option in the context menu for the BAT file or the shortcut.  If I use Windows Explorer to browse to `~/bin`, the *Applications Tool* ribbon has a button to pin the shortcut, but it's grayed out.

I am baffled by why something so simple in the past is so complicated now, costing the afternoon.